# Find the X or Y value when provided the instantaneous rate of change and the function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

Function: $h(x) = x^2+3x+2$

Instantaneous rate of change = $1$

I think you are supposed to use the difference quotient but reorder it somehow to solve for $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the derivative, plug in 1 for y, solve for x. Done.

so $H'(x) = 2x+ 3, 1= 2x+3, x=-1. $

If you don't know derivatives, then yes, you will just use the different quotient, but you will set it equal to 1. The difference quotient is just a rate of change, but it becomes instantaneous as h becomes arbitrarily small. This is usually called a derivative. A quick way to get what I got above is to use something called the power rule, but you will get the same thing.

Edit: Then you plug the $x$ you get back into your equation and you get the y-value. If you know limits, you're essentially taking $\lim{h\rightarrow0} [f(x+h)-f(x)]/h$, so you're goal is to factor the h out of the numerator so that it cancels with the denominator, and then you'll get a linear function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for my lack of competence but how did you find the derivative and why do you plug in 1 for y?

Comment: Oh, I just assumed you knew calculus, sorry. Lemme fix that.